# Charfield validation in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

I want a charfield which would give validation error if value of this field through the form is equal to "ashish". I haven't found any way to do this in django form.

field = django_forms.Charfield(required=true)

Is there any to write any regex or regex in place of required?

Comment: You haven't found *any* way to do it with a form? What, not even by following the [very clear instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) on how to validate a specific field and simply compare it against your value?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any regex to simple string comparison:

```
class MyForm(django_forms.Form):

    def clean_field(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['field']
        if value == 'ashish':
            raise django_forms.ValidationError('ashish is not alloved here.')
        return value
```